# VB.net, Excel VSTO, Delete empty column

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto

I'm trying to port some VBA code to VB.Net. I'm using Visual Studio 2022, Excel Add-in template.

I have an excel sheet with multiple columns. Some of the columns are blank and need to be deleted. I have the code working in Excel's VBA, but haven't been able to get it working in VB.net. I keep getting the error in code

```
If app.CountA(currentSheet.Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
```

The error is "exception is User-Unhandled: Member not found"

VBA working code:

```
    Dim iCounter As Long 'used in column delete
    
    'Delete empty columns
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange 'Should be on GR4100
    For iCounter = MyRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Application.CountA(Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
            Columns(iCounter).Delete
        End If
    Next iCounter
```

VB.net code I've tried, but doesn't work:

````
        Dim wkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook =
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook

        Dim ActiveWorksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet =
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

        Dim currentSheet As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet =
            Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(ActiveWorksheet)

        Dim MyRange As Range 'used in column delete
        Dim iCounter As Long 'used in column delete

        'Delete empty columns
        MyRange = currentSheet.UsedRange 'Should all cells with content
        For iCounter = MyRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
            If app.CountA(currentSheet.Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
                currentSheet.Columns(iCounter).Delete
            End If
        Next iCounter
       Dim MyRange As Range 'used in column delete
        Dim iCounter As Long 'used in column delete

        'Delete empty columns
        MyRange = currentSheet.UsedRange 'Should be on GR4100
        For iCounter = MyRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
            If app.CountA(currentSheet.Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
                currentSheet.Columns(iCounter).Delete
            End If
        Next iCounter```
````

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
Sub deleteEmptyColumn()
    Dim app As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application =
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application

    Dim wkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook =
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook

    Dim sheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet =
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    'Get the column count
    Dim columnCount As Integer = sheet.Columns.Count()

    Dim MyRange = sheet.UsedRange 'Should be on GR4100
    For iCounter = MyRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        If app.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheet.Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
            sheet.Columns(iCounter).Delete
        End If
    Next iCounter
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).